# Multi-platform diary application

Tags: windows, macos, software-rec

Can you recommend a good offline multi-platform (or just only Mac and Windows) diary application? One that allows different entries which also can be tagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Rednotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) - free and opensource. I use it and I am satisfied. For Windows, there is also portable version available on Portableapps.com :-)

[image]

Comment: it looks really nice. the only problem i see, is that for using it in osx snow leopard I tried to get the macports version an failed to execute (some python problem) and then there is some guide for installing it from source http://jamesthedisciple.wordpress.com/2010/04/09/rednotebook-on-osx-how-to/

Comment: so good luck! I cannot help you with Mac as I only have experience with Windows/Linux and also almost do not have experience with installing from source. So it is up to you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) is always the popular one.

Too bad [OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/) isn't on the Mac yet. That would be my favorite.  While [there is a Webapp version](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-onenote/archive/2010/06/08/the-onenote-web-app-is-here.aspx), it doesn't cut it for us hardcore OneNote users.

Comment: yeah, forgot to say I am looking for an offline app

Comment: Works just as well offline.  You **don't have** to use the online sync.